# how to display the data per hour ago in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
data = [
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:20:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:12:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:13:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 12:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 11:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 07:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 01:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 01:30:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 01:20:01'
    },
]
```

expected output:

```
 data = [
        {
            'name' : 'sample'
            'date' : '2020-02-18 13:50:01'
        },
        {
            'name' : 'sample'
            'date' : '2020-02-18 12:50:01'
        },
        {
            'name' : 'sample'
            'date' : '2020-02-18 11:50:01'
        },
        {
            'name' : 'sample'
            'date' : '2020-02-18 07:50:01'
        },
    ]
```

what I want to do here is to display the data per hour.
the data will filter like this.

```
data = [
            {
                'name' : 'sample'
                'date' : '2020-02-18 13:50:01'
            },
            {
                'name' : 'sample'
                'date' : '2020-02-18 12:50:01'
            },
            {
                'name' : 'sample'
                'date' : '2020-02-18 11:50:01'
            },
            {
                'name' : 'sample'
                'date' : '2020-02-18 07:50:01'
            },
        ]
```

it will not get the other data not hour ago. if the data is last 30minutes it will not get/display. the data should be last hour ago, data should be per hour ago. it should be dynamic. because if there's a new data which is
date: 2020-02-18 14:00:01, then per hour ago:

2020-02-18 14:00:01,

2020-02-18 13:00:01,

2020-02-18 12:00:01, etc...

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnbses?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group objects in an array per hour in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560448/group-objects-in-an-array-per-hour-in-javascript)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz can you give some example in typescript.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnbses?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour`:

```
const result = data.reduce((a, { name, date }) => {
    let currentDate = new Date(date);
    let dateHour = currentDate.getFullYear() + '/' + currentDate.getMonth()  
        + '/' +  currentDate.getDate()  + '/' +  currentDate.getHours();
    a[dateHour] = a[dateHour] || {name, date};
    return a;
}, {})
```

An example:

```js
let data = [
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 13:50:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 13:20:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 13:12:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 13:13:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 12:50:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 11:50:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 07:50:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 01:50:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 01:30:01'
  },
  {
      'name' : 'sample',
      'date' : '2020-02-18 01:20:01'
  },
]

const result = data.reduce((a, { name, date }) => {
  let currentDate = new Date(date);
  let dateHour = currentDate.getFullYear() + '/' + currentDate.getMonth()  + '/' +  currentDate.getDate()  + '/' +  currentDate.getHours();
  a[dateHour] = a[dateHour] || {name, date};
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I've created a `GetDataForHour(dataArray, dateToCompare)` function which might be the answer.
It filters the `dataArray` and returns only array entities having dates before the `dateToCompare` with the same minutes and seconds

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzzkfq